# Should the difference between taxable pay and gross pay be roughly equal to pension contributions

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, payroll

I am in the UK. My employeer changed payroll provider and ever since there has been many issues. With my old provider the difference between taxible pay and gross pay was almost exactly the pension contributions I had made at round 10%. Now with the new provider the isnt the case and the gap is quite much smaller, as if they havent recognised most of the pension payments. Is this likely to be a fault with payroll or am I misunderstanding something

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have a statement from your pension provider (or online access to your pension account) stating how much is being paid in?

Your payslip should also explicitly state total gross pay and pension contribution. Is the gross pay the same as it was before?

I would follow this up with your accounts department - it does sound as though the payroll company has been given the wrong information about your intended pension contributions.

Comment: The new pay slips are really hard to understand, I did raise concerns months ago but it wasnt until I recently got the P60 and typed it into my tax return that it highlight "the issue". My march payslip doesnt explicitly state the pension contributions to date either, I am lost as none of the numbers seem to add up!

Comment: Your accounts department should definitely be willing to explain the payslip to you. If you don't have direct access to them then go through your line manager?